# Zooming and panning to lat/lng span in map activity

Tags: android, mapactivity

**Summary**

I need to be able to move from my current mapview to a latitude/longitude span. I want this move to happen in an animated sort of way (similar to how `animateTo` works). I need to go from my current view, and zoom in or out to end up at the target latitude/longitude span. Below is the code I'm using to do this when I use zoomLevels. But I have to use spans, not zoom levels to accomplish this.

[Edit]

Here's what I'm doing for `animateTo`. I need the equivalent of this, but using Lat/Lng Span to end up at my final view (i need to be zoomed and centered, showing the lat/lng span provided). As you'll notice, i'm using `targetZoomLevel` and `currentZoomLevel` to determine how much zooming to do... I need to be using the lat/lng span instead.

```
public static void smoothZoom(final MapController controller,
        final int currentZoomLevel, final int targetZoomLevel,
        int latitude, int longitude) {

    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    controller.animateTo(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            int currentZoom = currentZoomLevel;
            int zoomTarget = targetZoomLevel;

            // Smooth zoom handler
            // int zoomLevel = _mapView.getZoomLevel();
            // int targetZoomLevel = targetLevel;
            long delay = 0;

            if (zoomTarget > currentZoom) {
                while (currentZoom++ < zoomTarget) {
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            controller.zoomIn();
                        }
                    }, delay);

                    delay += 150; // Change this to whatever is good on the
                                    // device
                }
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

[Edit]

I really need this code for my application now, there is no way around it. First person to help me get working code gets 250 rep.

Comment: this is bad  SO'ing. You should never be asking people to write code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the kind of solution you're looking for?

```
public static void zoomSpan(final MapView mapView, int northernLat, int southernLat, int easternLon, int westernLon) {
    final int latSpan = northernLat - southernLat;
    final int lonSpan = easternLon - westernLon;
    latCenter = southernLat + latSpan / 2;
    lonCenter = westernLon + lonSpan / 2;

    final MapController controller = mapView.getController();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable zoomRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int viewLatSpan = mapView.getLatitudeSpan();
            int viewLonSpan = mapView.getLongitudeSpan();
            boolean actionTaken = false;
            if (mapView.getZoomLevel() > 1 && (latSpan > viewLatSpan || lonSpan > viewLonSpan)) {
                controller.zoomOut();
                actionTaken = true;
            }
            if (mapView.getZoomLevel() < mapView.getMaxZoomLevel() && latSpan * 2 <= viewLatSpan && lonSpan * 2 <= viewLonSpan) {
                controller.zoomIn();
                actionTaken = true;
            }
            if (actionTaken)
                handler.post(zoomRunnable);
        }
    };

    controller.animateTo(latCenter, lonCenter, zoomRunnable);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me:

```
MapController.setCenter(GeoPoint);
```

You can get MapController from:

```
MapView.getController();
```

And get a GeoPoint from:

```
new GeoPoint( (int) ( LAT * 1e6 ) , (int) ( LONG * 1e6 )  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt... but that's not at all what I'm asking. You can use `animateTo` with the GeoPoint, and pass a Runnable to it, and create a custom animation doing that. Which is great... I can accomplish this no problem. I'm attempting to do the same thing... BUT with a `zoomToSpan`, rather than a `animateTo`. That's the question here.

Answer (score 1):

In my map application I needed to implement a location search feature. If location found it moves to that location, add an overlay and zooms to a predefined level.
I used following code for this purpose:

```
final int SEARCH_ZOOM_LEVEL = 7;

controller = mMapView.getController();
controller.setZoom(SEARCH_ZOOM_LEVEL );
pointToLocation(s);        // s is the location
```

pointToLocation() was implements like this:

```
private void pointToLocation(String s) {
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(MapDemo.this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocationName(
                s, 5);
        String add = "";
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            point = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));
            controller.animateTo(point);
        }    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MapDemo.this, "Location not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't use pre-defined levels. I *HAVE* to use lat/lng span to determine what the layout will be at the end of the zooming. I need the code that will zoom me (smoothly) to that lat/lng span... similar to how animateTo works with my smoothZoom for zoom levels.

Comment: So If I understand you correctly, you need a way to get the correct zooming level for your path/coordinates instead of defining it by yourself?

Comment: Correct. I have a current lat/lng span. I have a target lat/lng span. I need to go from my current lat/lng span, to my target lat/lng span... but not by using `zoomToSpan` (which immediately resets the mapview to that span)... I need the map to pan and zoom to that location (similar to how my smoothZoom function works).

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the function you're looking at is zoomToSpan(int latSpanE6, int lonSpanE6).

You have the current span (or can get it easily) and the target span (as you said you know it), so why don't you simply start calling zoomToSpan on a delay , as you incrementally move latSpanE6 and longSpanE6 towards the target. It shouldn't be that difficult. You already have most of the code there, but instead of zoomIn while checking the zoom level, you would zoomToSpan while checking if latSpanE6 and longSpanE6 have reached your target span.

Won't bother coding it since you can do it yourself ;)